# 'list' object not callable when INSERT into database

Tags: json, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to populate a database using a query API there are multiple lists within the JSON Payload but I can't seem to get the it right.

When I print I get: 'list' object is not callable.

The program runs fine and my data is runs but the SQL statement trips up what I am trying to do. Do I need to declare a dictionary?

```
import json
import urllib.request
import sqlite3
import urllib.parse


connection = sqlite3.connect("database.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()


# API endpoint
API_KEY = ''
API_ENDPOINT = "https://api.newsfilter.io/public/actions?token={}".format(API_KEY)
print(API_ENDPOINT)
# Define the filter parameters


queryString = "symbols: FRSX AND publishedAt:[2021-03-20 TO 2021-04-02]"
#{}".format(mydict)

payload = {
    "type": "filterArticles",
    "queryString": queryString,
    "from": 0,
    "size": 200
}

# Format your payload to JSON bytes
jsondata = json.dumps(payload)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('utf-8')

# Instantiate the request
req = urllib.request.Request(API_ENDPOINT)

# Set the correct HTTP header: Content-Type = application/json
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
# Set the correct length of your request
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))

# Send the request to the API
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)

# Read the response
res_body = response.read()

# Transform the response into JSON
assets = json.loads(res_body.decode("utf-8"))


articles = assets["articles"]


for asset in articles:
    #print(asset)
    try:
         cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO news_SEC (id, title, description, url, imageurl, publishedAt, source, symbol, cik) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
    """,(articles('id'), articles('title'), articles('description'), articles('url'), articles('imageurl'), articles('publishedAT'), articles('source'), articles('symbol'), articles('cik')))
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(asset)
    

connection.commit()
```

Comment: inside your for loop you want to access data via `asset["id"]` rather than `articles["id"]`. The former likely being a dict while the latter is a list/array of dict and hence why you get an error attempting to index into a list with a string.

Comment: That was was what I originally had but now it's telling me 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Try square brackets rather than round `asset["id"]` or `asset.get("id)` rather than `asset("id")`